# Forces applied to cam with different rocker ratio's

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

In a typical older automotive engine, the valves were opened by rocker arms, pushrods, and lifters riding on a camshaft.  As the camshaft rotates, upwards force is applied to the rocker arm which then opens the valve.  Spring tension is applied to the system to keep the lifter on the camshaft.   The typical rocker arm had a 1.5 ratio, where as the valve moves 1 + 1/2 more the hight of the camshaft lobe.

By changing to a 1.65 or higher ratio arm, will the camshaft / lifter interface see more force or pressure because of the leverage on the rocker arm ( not counting the increased spring pressure or valve travel distance ) ?

Valve springs will increase pressure by about 8% for every .050" compression, but is there a hidden increase in pressures due to the different leverage?

Comment: Moment = force * distance  so you increase one and decrease the other.

Answer (score 0):

The force applied by the lifter to the cam lobe will be about the same ratio as the valve lift. Assuming the spring force is linear over the range of compression movement. So if one replaces a 1.5 ratio arm with a 1.8 ratio arm the lobe/lifter force would increase 20 % ( 1.2 X the original force). One must be sure the spring is not being compressed close to it's solid height. The valve spring retainer washer is the weak link in the extreme case of the springs approaching solid height.

Comment: So its just a matter of spring pressure?

Comment: What if the total lift stays the same but you change the lobe and rocker ratio, both ratio's 1.5 and 1.8 open the valve the same amount, does the lifter pressure change?   Just seems like with more ratio, you would need more force, one for the quicker opening, and two for the shorter lever to operate the rocker.